# How to do different kinds of triangles in C?

Tags: c

Question is pretty basic, but I need to learn it to pass my first programming exam in college, so any help is above appreciated. 
So far I can only do normal, pyramid schemed triangle consisted of stars, with height dependent on input, which suggests how limited my knowledge is.

What I need to learn is how to do triangles that consist of different characters than star using for loops, for example:

for n=7

`ABCDEFG
  HIJKLM
   NOPQR
    STUV
     WXY
      ZA
       B`

or using hexadecimals

`0
 12
 345
 6789
 ABCDE
 F01234
 56789AB`

Any additional help would be highly appreciated, but code alone would be just as much fine, since I need to figure out how to put repeating alphabet or other symbols in place of stars.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you write a program to print the characters "A" to "Z" by using a loop using the numbers 0 to 25 and the fact that the ASCII value of "A" is 65?

Comment: I can't sadly, and I have no idea where to even start

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/631379a8e25d59c01f7922dfdd26be92

Answer (score 0):

I would just first define strings of characters you want to display

```
const char* LETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const char* HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

And then you can easily access the char you want by indexing these strings, modulo their lengths, like this:

```
char c;
const int LETTERS_LEN = strlen(LETTERS);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    c = LETTERS[i % LETTERS_LEN];
    // place c in your triangle
}
```

The `i % LETTERS_LEN` causes `i` to take values from `0` to `LETTERS_LEN - 1` periodically, which is exactly what you need (if I understand your example correctly).

Alternative solution would be to use the fact that 'A' ASCII code is 65, and you could just do `c = 65 + i % 26` but the solution I wrote is more versatile - you can define any set of characters you want.

Note: I haven't used pure C for a while now, I might have gotten the initialization part wrong. If you get compilation errors, just use `#define LETTERS "ABC..."`

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the complete program for you since it's a homework assignment. It sounds like you got the drawing of the triangles down and you just need help on how to use different characters. What I would probably do is create an array of characters:

```
char symbols[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

Then create an index pointer, starting at 0:

```
int index = 0;
```

Then, as you draw your symbol using `symbols[index]`, you just increment `index` and check to make sure it's not over the length. If it is, you reset `index` back to `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a good start. I still have to find a way to link the array characters with the actual traingle though, but your help is life saving